# Radare2 doesn't update current address, when single-step debugging using `ds`?

Tags: debugging, radare2

> Radare2 doesn't update current address, when single-step debugging using `ds`?

I'm debugging an ELF binary on Linux using single-step (`ds`). The problem is that the current address at the prompt doesn't update after each step.

The prompt:

[image]

How do I make Radare2 update the prompt to reflect the current value of EIP?

Furthermore, is it possible to make Radare2 automatically disassemble the next instruction after each `ds`, like it is possible with GDB?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make Radare2 update the prompt to reflect the current value of EIP?

Just use `e cmd.prompt = sr PC` for it. See [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21580/radare2-show-current-rip-and-current-instruction-while-stepping) and [issue](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/12581) for more details.

> Furthermore, is it possible to make Radare2 automatically disassemble the next instruction after each ds, like it is possible with GDB?

Not automatic solution, but you can do `pd1` each time you want to see the next instruction to perform.

However, if you want it **badly** to be automatic, you can modify the source code to perform `pd1` automatically for you. To do so, you want to modify `libr/core/cmd_debug.c`. Just find the place where `ds` is handled and put relevant code there like so:
[image: r2_pd1]

Then run `make` and enjoy the new functionality.
[image: r2_pd1_added]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use `pd` with the temporary seek operator `@` passing `rip` register so that `pd` will work from that address.

So instead of `pd` just use `pd@rip` and you should be fine with that.

```
[0x00000000]> pd
    ;-- rsi:
    0x00000000      ff             invalid
    ...


[0x00000000]> pd@rip
    ;-- rip:
    ┌─> 0x10000b3bf      4c892424       mov qword [rsp], r12
    ╎   0x10000b3c3      4489ea         mov edx, r13d
    ╎   0x10000b3c6      4c89f9         mov rcx, r15
```

Additionally you can use the `V!`-mode (or any other graphical view mode for that matter) view for debugging. They get automatically updated after you step over your binary.

Comment: Thank you - do you think it is a bug in Radare2? Or what's the reason for not updating the prompt address?

Comment: no. I think your seek position is just unrelated to the `rip` while debugging. You can imagine doing some stepping and investigating data at some other address. If you seek position changes every time you step it might be also frustrating.

Comment: But sometimes the prompt address update, e.g. after pressing `ds`, say, 10 times?  Do you know if it is possible to make Radare2 update the prompt address after each `ds`? Also, do you know if it is possible to make Radare2 automatically disassembly the next instruction after each `ds` (GDB can do that)?