# How to make Radare2 automatically disassemble next instruction after each `ds` debug single-step?

Tags: debugging, radare2

> How to make Radare2 automatically disassemble next instruction after each `ds` debug single-step?

I thought that `e asm.bytes=1` would achieve this, but that doesn't help.

In particular, GDB supports disassembling the next instruction after each debug single-step, so I guess this should be possible with Radare2 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute another command after doing `ds` you can simply use `;` to add a new command. So for example, the command `ds; pd 1 @ rip` will step one instruction and disassemble the instruction at `rip`.

You can also define a macro (an alias) for a set of commands. Let's define for example the macro `foo` to do the following things:

1. Single step
2. Print hexdump of 16 bytes at `rip`
3. Disassemble 1 instruction at `rip`

To do this you can simply run:

```
[0x7f46fea5ee00]> (foo, ds, px 16 @ rip, pd 1 @ rip)
```

And then use it with `.(foo)`:

```
[0x7f46fea5ee00]> .(foo)
- offset -       0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x7f46fea5ee1a  89c0 48c1 e220 4809 c248 8b05 0e70 0200  ..H.. H..H...p..
            ;-- rip:
            0x7f46fea5ee1a      89c0           mov eax, eax

[0x7f46fea5ee00]> .(foo)
- offset -       0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x7f46fea5ee1c  48c1 e220 4809 c248 8b05 0e70 0200 4889  H.. H..H...p..H.
            ;-- rip:
            0x7f46fea5ee1c      48c1e220       shl rdx, 0x20

[0x7f46fea5ee00]> .(foo)
- offset -       0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x7f46fea5ee20  4809 c248 8b05 0e70 0200 4889 156f 6802  H..H...p..H..oh.
            ;-- rip:
            0x7f46fea5ee20      4809c2         or rdx, rax
```

---

**Visual Modes**

Now, after all this was said, I want to add that in my opinion, interactive debugging using `ds`, `dso`, `dc` and similar are the wrong approach. For a debugging session, it is preferred to use the Visual Modes of radare2. Visual Panels mode is ideal for debugging session but you can also enjoy from a good experience while using the regular Visual and Visual Graph modes.

The following GIF shows the Visual Panels mode (`V!`) as well as the regular Visual mode. You can also see that by pressing `:` I can execute radare2 commands (in the gif I executed `px`). Visual Panels mode is very configurable and you can tweak it as you see fit. Simply use the `?` key to see the help and the available commands.

[image]

---

**Read more:**

- [Visual Modes | r2 book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/visual_mode/intro.html)
- [Visual Panels Mode | r2book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/visual_mode/visual_panels.html)
- [Macros | r2book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/scripting/macros.html)

Comment: thank you a lot. Now, how do I save the macro, so that it is loaded at next startup of Radare2? Furthermore, do you know why `ds` doesn't update the prompt address in https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20114/radare2-doesnt-update-current-address-when-single-step-debugging-using-ds/20118?noredirect=1#comment32446_20118? The prompt address only updates after pressing like 5-10 `ds`'s, but that varies.

Comment: You can simply write (echo) it to your radare2rc file (default is: `~/.radare2rc`). And for the seek, I don't know if it should be changed at all. If you think so, you can open an issue on GitHub or just ask in the radare2 telegram/irc group. Alos, you can add `s rip` to your macro in order to make r2 seek to the IP.

Comment: Ahh yes, you are probably right. However, it is just wierd then that after pressing `ds` many times, the seek address is suddenly updated. That doesn't make sense does it? Anyway, thanks for your answer. I will accept it :)