# Radare2 show current RIP and current instruction while stepping

Tags: radare2

How can I get the same behavior as in gdb when using disassemble-next-line on?

When I step in radare2, I just see:

```
[0x7fea91263220]> ds
[0x7fea91263220]> ds
[0x7fea91263220]> ds
```

Why doesn't it increment? How do I get it to show what instruction it is at?

Comment: Not a bug: "Because its the prompt shows the seek not the rip. You can do e cmd.prompt=sr PC if you want that behaviour" https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/12581

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug: "Because its the prompt shows the seek not the rip. You can do e cmd.prompt=sr PC if you want that behaviour" https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/12581

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to set it to `e cmd.prompt=sr PC`, you could also use the commands`sr rip` or `sr PC` to show rip when needed.
By the way, could you please mark your answer as accepted? 
(my reputation is not high enough, so i cant comment your answer)